# f inverse of f(a)

Tags: inverse

$f\left(x\right)=x^{2}-4x+8$, for $x\ge2$

If $a\le0$, find $f^{-1}\left(f\left(a\right)\right)$.

I know $f^{-1}\left(x\right)=2+\sqrt{x-4}$

How to solve my qn then.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio EDITED, that is what i know.

Comment: Do you know it in the sense that you've proved that $f:[2,\infty)\to \operatorname{im}\left.f\right\rvert_{[2,\infty)}$ is bijective and $f^{-1}(x)=2+\sqrt{x-4}$ for all $x\in \operatorname{im}\left.f\right\rvert_{[2,\infty)}$ ?

Comment: wth it's just the inverse, u dont need 2 know all that. I want to find the inverse of f(a) moreso.

Comment: Ok, fine by me.

Comment: can u solve my problem tho?

Comment: If you have trouble writing in English try using https://translate.google.com/

Comment: @TheQuantumObsession Oh, no, I would have to ask other questions and I'm quite done with that. Happy Easter, though.

Comment: @jjagmath Bro im fluent in english, what?

Comment: How do you compute $f(a)$ when $a$ is not in the domain?

Comment: bu er dao Liding Yao

Comment: $f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2-4x+8, &\text{for $x\ge 2$}\\
\text{what?}&\text{for $x<2$}\end{cases}$

Comment: @TheQuantumObsession You should definitely explain where this problem comes from, at least some context. Otherwise this problem will be closed since it doesn't follow the guideline well.

Answer (score 0):

If $a<0$, since $f(x)$ has domain $[2,\infty)$, $f(a)$ does not exist (or is not defined, depending on your preferred terminology).

The rest of the question is therefore meaningless.

If you would like to check your question and ask it again, I'm sure people would be glad to assist.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^2-4x+8 = (x-2)^2+4$

to find the inverse we set $f(x)=y $ and solve for $x$ which you did perfectly

So we have $f^{-1}(x)=2+\sqrt {x-4} , x \in (- \infty,2] $

and  $f^{-1}(x)= 2- \sqrt{x-4}  , x \in [2,+ \infty)$

In your original question you said $f$ is defined for $x \geq 2$ and $a \leq 0$ so we cannot put $a$ inside of $f$.

Although if we define $f$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

now it is meaningful to ask what $f^{-1}(f(a))$ is.

We know that $f^{-1}(x)=y \iff f(y)=x
$ from the defenition of inverse functions

so if we sub the $x$ in the first equation with $f(y)$ we get that $f^{-1}(f(y))=y $

if we let $y=a \implies f^{-1}(f(a))=a $ and that's the answer.